# How to run a rundeck job like a rest call from application?

Tags: api, jobs, rundeck

I created a simple job of mkdir in rundeck.Now I wanted to run that job some node application.So how can I get the api for the job so that I can call that rest call from my application and run the job.

I just tried a post call for this from my postman but didnt worked.

http://rundeckhost:4440/api/1/job/uuid/run

Gave the following error:
(unauthenticated) is not authorized for: /api/1/job/ec0852b7-222a-4372-ad4b-808892777019/executions

Can someone point me to any references or any info on how can we run the job through a rest call from our application.Basically how to get the rest url for the job to run?

Answer (score 1):

You have one of two ways to authenticate: http://rundeck.org/docs/api/#authentication

For your purpose it will probably be easier to use the authtoken type. See here for your choices for authtoken types: http://rundeck.org/docs/administration/access-control-policy.html#api-token-authorization

Roughly, you will do something like this:

```
curl -H "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: $API_TOKEN" \
    --data-urlencode "${NODEFILTER:-}" \
    --data-urlencode "argString=${JOB_OPTIONS:-}" \
    -X POST "${RD_URL}/api/12/job/$JOB_UUID/run"
```